# Return selected value in a form using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, cart

I need to get the values selected for a location form and add it's value to a cart. All the other information in the form is gathered correctly. Here is the code in the form:

```
<section class="cards">
        @foreach($rentals as $rental)
        <article class="cards-item">
            <figure class="card product">
                <div class="card-images">
                    <img src="{{ asset('img/rentals' . $rental->image)  }}" alt="" >
                </div>
                <figcaption class="card-content">
                <h1 class="card-title">{{ $rental->title }}</h1>
                <h2 class="card-title product_title">{{ $rental->name }}</h2>
                <p class="card-text" style="text-align:left;">{{ $rental->description }}
                    {{-- <a href="img/pdf/mcelroy-spec/2lc-spec-sheet.pdf" target="_blank">Download Spec Sheet</a> --}}
                </p>
                <form action="{{ route('cart.store') }} " method="POST">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="formrow" style="margin-right: -10;">
                            <div class="formitem col1of2" style="float: left;">
                                <label class="label" for="location" style="float:left;">Pick Up Location</label>
                                <select name="location" id="location" class="location">
                                    <option>please choose</option>
                                    <option value="bkf">Bakersfield</option>
                                    <option value="ch">Chico</option>
                                    <option value="fsn">Fresno</option>
                                    <option value="hyw">Hayward</option>
                                    <option value="mtc">Manteca</option>
                                    <option value="oak">Oakley</option>
                                    <option value="rwc">Redwood City</option>
                                    <option value="sac">Sacramento</option>
                                    <option value="sal">Salinas</option>
                                    <option value="sj">San Jose</option>
                                    <option value="sjf">San Jose Fusion</option>
                                    <option value="sr">Santa Rosa</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $rental->id }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="{{ $rental->title }}">
                    {{-- <input type="hidden" name="pickup-date" value="pickupDate">
                    <input type="hidden" name="return-date" value="returnDate"> --}}
                    <input type="hidden" name="location" value="{{ $rental->location }}">
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <div class="back">
                            <button class="primary button" type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </article>
    </section>
</article>
```

@endforeach

And here is the code in the cart view:

```
<section class="main-content">
<section class="content">
    <article>
        @if(session()->has('success_message'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session()->get('success_message') }}
        </div>
        @endif
        <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
        @if(count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        @endif
        @if (Cart::count() > 0)
        <h2>{{ Cart::count() }} item(s) in Shopping Cart</h2>
        <div>
            <div>
                @foreach (Cart::content() as $item)
                <fieldset>
                    <article class="js-cart-product">
                        <p class="prod-title">Name: {{$item->model->name}} </p>
                        <p class="pu-date">Pick up date: {{$item->pickupDate}} </p>
                        <p class="rtn-date">Return Date: {{$item->returnDate}}</p>
                        <p class="loc">Location: {{$item->location}}</p>
                        <form action="{{ route('cart.destroy', $item->rowId)}}" method="POST">
                            {{csrf_field()}}
                            {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                            <div class="buttons">
                                <div class="back">
                                    <button class="primary button" type="submit">Delete Item</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- <div class="cart__footer">
                                <p class="cart__text">
                                    <a class="button" href="#" title="Buy products">
                                        Check Out
                                    </a>
                                </p>
                            </div> -->
                        </form>
                    </article>
                </fieldset>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
        @else
        <h3>No items in Cart!</h3>
        <a href="{{ route('rental equipment')}} ">Return to Rental Equipment</a>
        @endif
    </div>
</article>
```

I my controller I have these values set:

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;



 use App\Rental;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Session;
    use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart;

    class CartController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function index()
        {
            return view('cart.cart');
        }

        /**
         * Show the form for creating a new resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function create()
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Store a newly created resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function store(Request $request)
        {

            $duplicates = Cart::search(function ($cartItem, $rowId) use ($request) {
                return $cartItem->id === $request->id;
            });
            if ($duplicates->isNotEmpty()) {
                return redirect()->route('cart.index')->with('success_message', 'Item is already in your cart!');
            }

             $this->validate($request, array(
                'location'=>'required',
            ));

            Cart::add($request->id, $request->title, 1, $request->location)
                ->associate('App\Rental');

            Session::flash('success', 'The item was successfully save!');

            return redirect()->route('cart.index');
        }

        /**
         * Display the specified resource.
         *
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function show($id)
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
         *
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function edit($id)
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Update the specified resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Remove the specified resource from storage.
         *
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function destroy($id)
        {
            Cart::remove($id);

            Session::flash('success', 'The item has been removed!');

            return redirect()->route('cart.index');
        }
```

My routes are as follows:

```
  Route::get('rental_equipment', 'PageContentController@rental_equipment')->name('rental equipment');
Route::resource('rentals','RentalController');
Route::get('/cart', 'CartController@index')->name('cart.index');
Route::post('/cart', 'CartController@store')->name('cart.store');
Route::delete('/cart/{id}', 'CartController@destroy')->name('cart.destroy');
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The `select` needs to be inside the `form`.

Comment: @ross wilson, that doesn't seem to work. I do get an error message that I need to supply a valid location, even when I select a location.

Comment: Are you using a package to create the cart and/or have you created your own validation for adding to the cart?

Comment: @RossWilson I am using this one: https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart I removed the pricing option as I don't need that and added the location in the config file.

Comment: Have you added your own validation?

Comment: @RossWilson no, do I need to add that into the controller? I am really new to Laravel so I am learning as I go along.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out why you're getting **supply a valid location** error.

Comment: @RossWilson I added this line into the controller:  ' $this->validate($request, array(
            'location'=>'required',
        ));' It jsut doesn't seem to be picking up any of the values when they are selected.

Comment: Are you using ajax or any sort of javascript to submit the form?

Comment: @RossWilson no I am using the Laravel Shopping Cart library to submit the form.

Comment: In that case can you edit your question to show the whole blade file, the route for `cart.store` from your routes file and the controller method for the route.

Comment: @RossWilson ok, I added in that information to the code.

Comment: You seem to have a hidden input that is also called `location`, I would suggest removing that and seeing if it works. Apologies, I'm not sure why I didn't notice this before.

Comment: @RossWilson that totally worked. Thank you.